# What is the formula for calculating the test metrics in Sonarqube?

Tags: math, sonarqube, metrics

I am using SonarQube 4.5.4 and I would like to know the formulas for the metric in the test field for Unit tests - consider image below. I get the value you find below. After reading [SonarQube's documentation on metrics](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions) I am still confused.

I only find Unit test success density in %. Let ρ be that density, m<sub>u</sub> the number of unit test, m<sub>e</sub> the number of Unit test errors and m<sub>f</sub> the number of Unit test failures. we then have

[image: $$ \rho = m_u - \left(\frac{m_e + m_f}{m_u}\cdot 100 \right)$$]

Is this correct? what is the formula for the other values?

[image: test data]

Answer (score 1):

So far, the only thing I can answer is that your formula isn't correct because you misread parentheses.

The correct formula is, with your notations:

[image: http://www.HostMath.com/Show.aspx?Code=%5Crho%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7Bm_u%20-%20(m_e%20%2B%20m_f)%7D%7Bm_u%7D%20%5Ccdot%20100]

The other values from your screenshot are defined in the docs (where "Coverage" is your "Unit Test Coverage"):

> Condition coverage = (CT + CF) / (2*B) 
>   Line coverage = LC / EL 
>   Coverage = (CT + CF + LC)/(2*B + EL)
>
> where
>
> CT = conditions that have been evaluated to 'true' at least once 
>   CF = conditions that have been evaluated to 'false' at least once 
>   LC = covered lines = lines_to_cover - uncovered_lines
>
> B = total number of conditions 
>   EL = total number of executable lines (lines_to_cover)

These numbers are between 0 and 1, multiply by 100 to get a percentage.

Comment: True. I might have read it to fast. so does coverage is equal unit test coverage?

Comment: Indeed, ``coverage`` means UT coverage. The formula is the same for IT coverage and Overall coverage, but he metrics that are used are different (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

UT Coverage (or coverage) is computed as follows (note that all variables are `Double`):

```
Double utCoverage = ((((totalConditions - totalUncoveredConditions) + totalLines) - totalUncoveredLines) / (totalConditions + totalLines)) * 100;
```

Using `conditions_to_cover`, `uncovered_conditions`, `lines_to_cover` and `uncovered_lines` metrics as values.

IT Coverage and Overall Coverage are computed using the same formula, however the metrics to use are different.

For IT Coverage you have to use `it_conditions_to_cover`, `it_uncovered_conditions`, `it_lines_to_cover`and `it_uncovered_lines` metrics.

For Overall Coverage you have to use `overall_conditions_to_cover`, `overall_uncovered_conditions`, `overall_lines_to_cover` and `overall_uncovered_lines` metrics.

If you're looking for the condition coverage formula, here it is:

```
Double conditionCoverage = ((totalConditions - totalUncoveredConditions) / totalConditions) * 100;
```

And the following one is for line coverage:

```
Double lineCoverage = ((totalLines - totalUncoveredLines) / totalLines) * 100;
```

Again, you have to use the right metrics to feed the formula (see above.)

Hope it helps.

Note: this is taken from my consolidated pdf report generation tool. It has been tested successfuly on projects representing more that 2 mio NCLOC and is used to produce weekly reports (in other words I'm pretty confident that it works.)